# How do I remove individual autofill suggestions from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

Sometimes, some things are better meant to be private and shouldn't be shown when others watch.

How can I remove individual auto-fill suggestions so that they don't re-appear?

I don't wish to remove them all because some auto-fill suggestions are handy to have...

---

Here is a *quick example* using the Ask Question button here, at least two questions don't belong there:

[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Hover the mouse cursor over each one and press the specified key.

Most browsers: <kbd>Del</kbd>

Chrome: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>

Mac + Chrome: <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>

In some browsers, this also works for removing history entries from the address bar.

Comment: Shift + Del worked fine in Chrome on my Mac

Comment: Just as a hint for dummies like myself: it's the delete button, not backspace. It wont work with backspace (or shift + backspace)

Comment: oh my god. this is beautiful. thank you so much.

Comment: Shift+Del doesn't do anything

Answer (score 3):

If [<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>] or [<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>] doesn't do it, there's another way to edit Autofill information in Chrome.

Click the Chrome menu (three horizontal bars at the far right of the browser toolbar), choose **Settings**, and then click **Show advanced settings...** at the bottom of the page.

Next, under the **Passwords and forms** heading, click **Manage Autofill settings**.

On the pop-up, double-click the item you want to edit.

On the second pop-up, hover over the info item you want to delete and click the **X** that appears to the right.

Finally, click **OK** to close the second pop-up and **Done** to close the first.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Mac with a keyboard that does not have separate Delete and Backspace buttons, just Delete. I use Chrome. For me, the answer by sblair above was exactly what worked for me, and I was unable to get it to work as it did for Django above. I used this technique to remove a previously entered incorrect username to a site and did not want that to confuse me in the future as a possible choice.

In short, I entered fn + shift + delete on a Mac with Chrome while hovered over the bad username entry in the dropdown choice of autofill entries.

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Is your last paragraph meant to be an **answer** to the OP's question? If so, please rewrite your answer to emphasize that, and consider de-emphasizing the commentary portion. This is not a discussion forum and as such we expect answers to be direct, not chatty.